# Как выровнять в последней строке одиночный флекс элемент по левому краю так, чтобы он выравнивался под элемент над ним?

Tags: css, flexbox

[image: flex][image: flex]

Нужно выровнять последний элемент под первым на предыдущей строке. display: flex; justify-content: center

Comment: код css в студию

Comment: https://github.com/xxxrePAPRIKA/Pulse
https://github.com/xxxrePAPRIKA/Pulse/blob/main/src/sass/blocks/_catalog.scss

Comment: Воспользуйтесь гридами.

Comment: Тут есть своя песочница, в ней все можно показать. Как пример смотри соседний, практически идентичный вопрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1502520/Последние-два-блока-слева-при-justify-content-space-between